# Does creating a compute_disk in gcp with a custom image incur additional costs for the image storage?

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I would like to create a google_compute_disk resource through terraform. If I want to create the disk with a custom image that is not from the ones provided by google, do I have to pay for storage for the image or is it free?

I went through the google and terraform docs but I was unable to find any information on this subject.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about specific programming issues.

Answer (score 0):

You pay for the storage of your custom image. The price depends on region, us-east1 (South Carolina) is $0.05 per GB. There might also be a network charge to read the custom image. For North America, the price is $0.02 per GB.

Pricing details are located here (scroll down to Custom image storage):

[Disk and image pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/disks-image-pricing)